# Why I can't compare string after I use simple json library?

Tags: java, json

Code:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();                        
for(Object type:entityObj.keySet()){
    String notableType=String.valueOf(type);
    System.out.println(notableType);
    String object="NotableType";
    if(notableType.equals(object)){
        map.put(entity.toString(), entityObj.get(type).toString());
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

This is weird. I tested the `String notableType` is exactly the string "NotableType" but the hash values between `object` and `notableType` are totally different. One is -1929035367 and one is 0.

Why? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Is notableType equals to "NotableType"? not to me in terms of case sensitive and also existence of quotes

Comment: Yeah They are equal. I tested a lot of times. I just use copy and paste but it still didn't work.

Comment: can you try using equalsIgnoreCase instead of equals?

Comment: What's your question exactly? If they are equal, then equals() returns true. If equals() returns false, then they're obviously not equal. Print the integer value of every character of both strings, and you'll see that they're actually different if equals() returns false.

Comment: white spaces...maybe? try trimming the notableType. `notableType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(object)`

Comment: I tested again the hash value became "108106". I don't know why. And the output of System.out.println(notableType); is "NotableType". I just copied and paste to the "equals" method. But I found here they are not equal.

Comment: It worked!!!! After trim and equalsIgnoreCase. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are surely not equal. You must have missed the white spaces after your string. Those things are easy to miss out.

`trim`ming the String should take care of this.

```
notableType.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(object)
```